# How to read parquet file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a parquet file using Python 3.6.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_parquet('smalldata.parquet')



df.head()
```

However, this is generating an error that module pandas has no attribute read_parquet. What dependencies should I cater in order to solve this problem?

Edit 1:

I updated Pandas and this is the stacktrace

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pandas in /home/fatima/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.24.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2011k in /home/fatima/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2018.9)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.12.0 in /home/fatima/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in /home/fatima/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in /home/fatima/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.12.0)
```

Edit 2:
this is what conda list gives me

```
pandas                    0.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: which pandas version are you using? can you try upgrading your pandas.

Comment: I recently downloaded Anaconda. Let me try and get back to you

Comment: `read_parquet` was added in 21.0, so it's likely that your `pandas` is older than that.

Comment: @gmds problem persists

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the required packages:

```
pip install pandas pyarrow s3fs fastparquet
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read Parquet files in Pandas, it may be that you don't have one of the engines installed for reading Parquet files, such as `pyarrow` or `fastparquet`. You would need to install those dependencies as Pandas `read_parquet` requires either of these engines in order to read Parquet files. For each of those dependencies, you would also need to figure out which dependencies are required for installing each of those libraries.

If this isn't the issue, can you please comment on what the error you are encountering may be?